# event not working on React not able to call function onClicking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

```
<div className="slider">
  <div className='wrapper'>
    <button onClick={()=> console.log('hello')} className="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></button>
    <div className="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></div>
    <section className='first'>
      <img src={img1} alt=""></img>
      <h2>Hellow</h2>
      <p>dakdjaflkfdjal f fjkajlfkasjlfdjflakflk asfjal k</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @SumanJ2000, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please create a [mre] of your issue so that we can reproduce your issue? You can use stack overflow's in-built code editor, here is how you can use it for react examples: [How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537). When using images, you don't need a closing tag, instead use `<img src={img1} alt="" />`

Comment: The problem might be that `img` because if you remove it your code works.

Comment: Could you try to write a name for the button? Like: <button> I'm a button. </button>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

passed a text to the button tag and it worked:

```
   <div className="slider">
        <div className="wrapper">
          <button onClick={() => console.log('hello')} className="fa fa-arrow-circle-right">
            click me
          </button>
          <div className="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></div>
          <section className="first">
            <img src={img1} alt=""/>
            <h2>Hellow</h2>
            <p>dakdjaflkfdjal f fjkajlfkasjlfdjflakflk asfjal k</p>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
```